# CodeIgniter/PHP Active Record won't increment an integer

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, codeigniter

Here's my query, in CodeIgniter's Active Record:

```
function calculate_invites($userid)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $userid)
               ->update('users', array('invites' => 'invites-1', 'sentinvites' => 'sentinvites+1'), FALSE);
}
```

The fields `invites` and `sentinvites` are both integers but are set to 0 after the function is run. This makes me presume that CodeIgniter is passing `invites-1` and `sentinvites+1`  as strings, but I thought appending `FALSE` to the end stopped it doing that?

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: since Ci- Active Record is't working nearly the way i expects an AC to work... here the ci-user-guide referral
[active_record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#set)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This doesn't work with `update`, only with `set`.

This should work:

```
$this->db->where('id', $userid);
$this->db->set('invites', 'invites-1', FALSE);
$this->db->set('sentinvites', 'sentinvites+1', FALSE);
$this->db->update('users');
```

This may work too (the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert) is a bit unclear):

```
$this->db->where('id', $userid);
$this->db->set(array('invites' => 'invites-1', 'sentinvites' => 'sentinvites+1'), FALSE);
$this->db->update('users');
```